# jQuery this selector not working in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have a function that appends new div with input text and a {button with add_key class}, after adding it I want to change the class and the text for the current button but $(this) not working and even I used **this.element** not working,
this is my click event function

```
$(document).on('click','.add_key',() => {
   $(this).prop('value', 'Delete');
   $(this).toggleClass('add_key del_key');
   $('#main_div').prepend(getUIComponentTemplate());
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Arrow functions have another behavior with `this`, look through the [**DOCS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for more info. So finally you have 2 options:

**1)** Don't use arrow functions, use old ES5 way:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_key', function() {
  $(this).prop('value', 'Delete');
  $(this).toggleClass('add_key del_key');
  $('#main_div').prepend(getUIComponentTemplate());
});
```

**2)** Replace `this` with `event.currentTarget`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_key', event => {
  $(event.currentTarget).prop('value', 'Delete');
  $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('add_key del_key');
  $('#main_div').prepend(getUIComponentTemplate());
});
```

Here is a small demo, which logs the element via these two ways:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add_key', function() {
  console.log(this);
});

$(document).on('click', '.add_key', event => {
  console.log(event.currentTarget);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="add_key">CLICK</h1>
```

Comment: @hezha, nice to hear that

Answer (score 1):

You're using an arrow function to define your event callback, which does not have a `this` value and instead uses the `this` of the enclosing execution context.  In this case, that would be the `document` object.

If you want to take advantage of the `this` context of the `.add_key` selector, you'll want to use the function syntax:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_key', function() {
    $(this).prop('value', 'Delete');
    $(this).toggleClass('add_key del_key');
    $('#main_div').prepend(getUIComponentTemplate());
});
```

This [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) does a decent job explaining the history behind the decision for this behavior.